# Como hacer para que no se me repitan los valores

Tags: python

```
def numerosEn(lista):
    sin_repetir = []
    for numero in lista:
        if numero[0] not in sin_repetir:
            sin_repetir.append(numero)
    return sin_repetir

numeros= [['p5', 93526], ['p5', 91019], ['p8', 90207], ['p5', 94878]]
print(numerosEn(numeros))
```

Al hacer funcionar el codigo me sigue repitiendo los numeros que hago en ese caso

Comment: Evita repetir la misma pregunta. Siempre puedes editarla.

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo tienes aquí:

```
if numero[0] not in sin_repetir:
    sin_repetir.append(numero)
```

Estás guardando la lista de valores completa, con lo cual para cada busqueda debes recorrer nuevamente todas las listas.

Viendo también tu pregunta anterior lo puedes solucionar creando un diccionario en que la clave sea 'p5' y el valor una lista con todos los valores para 'p5'

```
def numerosEn(lista):
    tiempos = {}
    for dato in lista:
        if dato[0] in tiempos:
            tiempos[dato[0]].append(dato[1])
        else:
            tiempos[dato[0]] = [dato[1]]
```

Ahora tienes los datos muy accesibles, solo falta saber qué quieres hacer con ellos.

Por ejemplo los valores mínimos de cada clave.

```
    listado = []
    for k, v in tiempos.items():
        m = min(v)
        listado.append([k,m])
    return listado
```

que lo puedes cambiar por esto:

```
    return [ [k, min(v)] for k, v in tiempos.items() ]
```

Devuelve:

`[['p5', 91019], ['p8', 90207]]`

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que hice fue convertir las listas en un str ya que el operador "in" solo funciona con str.
Espero haberte ayudado, aquí esta el código arreglado:

```
def numerosEn(lista):
sin_repetir = []
for numero in lista:
    if str(numero[0]) not in str(sin_repetir):
        sin_repetir.append(numero)
return sin_repetir

numeros= [['p5', 93526], ['p5', 91019], ['p8', 90207], ['p5', 94878]]
print(numerosEn(numeros))
```

Devuelve:

```
[['p5', 93526], ['p8', 90207]]
```